# Angular - core.js:6456 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'first_name')

Tags: angular

I am implementing dynamic FormArray update in Angular-12

```json
    {
      "message": "Employee Detail.",
      "error": false,
      "code": 200,
      "results": {
        "employee": {
            "id": 8,
            "first_name": "JONAH",
            "last_name": "YAKUBU",
            "other_name": "AKWETEY",
            "employeecontacts": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "phone_type_id": 2,
                    "employee_id": 8,
                    "phone_number": "014566778",
                    "is_primary_contact_number": 1,
                    "phonetypes": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "type_name": "Arena",
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "phone_type_id": 3,
                    "employee_id": 8,
                    "phone_number": "016766709",
                    "is_primary_contact_number": 0,
                    "phonetypes": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "type_name": "Office",
                    }
                }
            ]
          }
      }
    }
```

Interface:

```js
    export class EmployeeResponse {
      results!: { employee: IEmployee; };
    }

    export interface IEmployee {
      id?: number;
      first_name?: string;
      other_name?: string;
      last_name?: string;
      employeecontacts?: IContact[];
    }

    export interface IContact {
      id?: number;
      phone_number: string;
      phone_type_id?: number;
      phonetypes?: {id:number,type_name:string};
      is_primary_contact_number?: boolean;
    }
```

service:

```js
    getEmployeeById(id: number): Observable<EmployeeResponse> {
      return this.http.get<EmployeeResponse>(this.api.baseURL + 'employees/fetchbyid/' + id, this.httpOptions);
    }

    public updateEmployee(id: number, employee: IEmployee): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.put(this.api.baseURL + 'employees/update/' + id, employee, this.httpOptions);
    }
```

component:

```js
_id!: number;
contactInfoForm!: FormGroup;
contactdata!: IEmployee;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this._id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  this.updateContact();
  this.loadContactById();
}

loadContactById() {
  this.employeeService
    .getEmployeeById(this._id)
    .subscribe((data: EmployeeResponse) => {
      this.contactdata = data.results.employee;
      this.contactInfoForm.patchValue({
        first_name: this.contactdata.first_name,

      });
  this.contactInfoForm.setControl(
    'contacts',
    this.SetExistingContacts(this.contactdata.employeecontacts || [])
  );
    });
}

SetExistingContacts(contactSets: IContact[]): FormArray {
  const formarray = new FormArray([]);
  contactSets.forEach(c => {
    formarray.push(this.fb.group({
      phone_number: c.phone_number,
      phone_type_id: c.phone_type_id,
      is_primary_contact_number: c.is_primary_contact_number
    }));
  });
  return formarray;
}

updateContact() {
  this.contactInfoForm = this.fb.group({
    id: [''],
    first_name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    contacts: this.fb.array([
      this.addContactFormGroup()
    ])
  });
}

addContactFormGroup(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
    phone_type_id: ['', Validators.required],
    phone_number: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(15)]],
    is_primary_contact_number: ['']
  });
}

public addContactButtonClick() {
  const contacts = this.contactInfoForm.get('contacts') as FormArray
  contacts.push(this.addContactFormGroup())
}

get contacts() {
  return this.contactInfoForm.controls['contacts'] as FormArray;
}

getContactFormGroup(index: number): FormGroup {
  return this.contacts.at(index) as FormGroup;
}

  onSubmitContact() {
// stop here if form is invalid
if (this.contactInfoForm.invalid) {
    return;
}
this.mapFormValueForContactModel();
this.employeeService.updateEmployee(this._id, this.contactdata).subscribe(res => {
  this.data = res;
  });
  }

  mapFormValueForContactModel() {
this.employee.first_name = this.contactInfoForm.value.first_name;
this.employee.employeecontacts = this.contactInfoForm.value.employeecontacts;
  }
```

HTML;

```html
<form [formGroup]="contactInfoForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitContact()">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="first_name">First Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div formArrayName="contacts" class="col-md-12">
      <div *ngFor="let contact of getContactsFormArray().controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <p>
          <b>Contact Phone : {{i + 1}}</b>
        </p>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="phone_number">Phone Number:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <div class="input-group mb-4">
                <ngx-intl-tel-input [cssClass]="'form-control mb-4'" [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries" [enableAutoCountrySelect]="false" [enablePlaceholder]="true" [searchCountryFlag]="true" [searchCountryField]="[SearchCountryField.Iso2, SearchCountryField.Name]"
                  [selectFirstCountry]="false" [selectedCountryISO]="CountryISO.Nigeria" [phoneValidation]="true" [separateDialCode]="true" name="phone_number" formControlName="phone_number">
                </ngx-intl-tel-input>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="getContactFormGroup(i).get('phone_number')!.touched && getContactFormGroup(i).get('phone_number')!.invalid">
              <div *ngIf="getContactFormGroup(i).get('phone_number')!.hasError('required')">
                <div class="text-danger">
                  Phone Number is required!
                </div>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="getContactFormGroup(i).get('phone_number')!.hasError('validatePhoneNumber')">
                <div class="text-danger">
                  Invalid Phone Number!
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="phone_type_id">Phone Type:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <ng-select [items]="phonetypes" [selectOnTab]="true" [searchable]="true" bindValue="id" bindLabel="type_name" placeholder="Select Phone Type" [multiple]="false" [clearable]="true" required formControlName="phone_type_id">
              </ng-select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="phone_type_id">Is Primary Line?:</label><br>
              <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck2" formControlName="is_primary_contact_number" (change)="onIsPrimaryContactChecked(i)">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <br><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-right" (click)="removeOrClearContact(i)" matTooltip="Remove Contact Phone No."><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i> Remove</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right" (click)="addContactButtonClick()" matTooltip="Add Contact Phone No."><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Add</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="isLoading" class="btn btn-success" (click)="contactValidate()">
                      <span *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
                      <i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> Save</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

As I tried to update the retrieved data from the dynamic FormArray, I got this error:

> core.js:6456 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'first_name')
> at EmployeeEditComponent.mapFormValueForContactModel (employee-edit.component.ts:770)
> at EmployeeEditComponent.onSubmitContact (employee-edit.component.ts:758)

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error above as you are accessing `this.employee` which is `undefined`.

You need to **assign the value to `this.employee`** before accessing its properties.

```js
loadContactById() {
  this.employeeService
    .getEmployeeById(this._id)
    .subscribe((data: EmployeeResponse) => {
        
      this.employee = data.results.employee;
        
      ...
    });
}
```

---

OR **use `this.contactdata` variable** as you are passing `this.contactdata` to `updateEmployee()`.

```js
onSubmitContact() {
  // stop here if form is invalid
  if (this.contactInfoForm.invalid) {
      return;
  }
  this.mapFormValueForContactModel();
  this.employeeService.updateEmployee(this._id, this.contactdata)
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.data = res;
    });
}
```

```js
mapFormValueForContactModel() {
  this.contactdata.first_name = this.contactInfoForm.value.first_name;
  this.contactdata.employeecontacts = 
  this.contactInfoForm.value.employeecontacts;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get what I'm sending to the backend. I'm getting this error there:   Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ... when I did console.log(this.data); from the fronend, I got undefined

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Is it from `getEmployeeById`? You may check the F12 Developer console + Network tab to see the response data returned by the API. And make sure that the response returned is the same type as `EmployeeResponse`.